# SQL BUG doesn't accept null when write !=

Tags: mysql, sql, null, isnull

When I write column!=something it also doesn't choose any null value and something. Why this happened? Can I prevent this just writing AND column is NULL?

Comment: Because `null` will allways be not fullfilling the condition if it is not beeing checked explicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for `NULL` too.

```
SELECT 
*
FROM your_table
WHERE column <> something
OR column IS NULL
```

**Note:** You cannot compare `NULL` with anything but `NULL`.

Let's look at the following code snippets:

```
SET @v := NULL;
SELECT @v = NULL;
Result: NULL; Because NULL can be only compared using IS NULL

SELECT @v IS NULL;
Result: 1 (i.e. TRUE)
```

> The NULL value can be surprising until you get used to it.
>   Conceptually, NULL means “a missing unknown value” and it is treated
>   somewhat differently from other values.
>
> To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL

[**WORKING WITH NULL VALUES IN MYSQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html)

Comment: Thank you for answering.First sentence was answer for me :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have check for NULL using the OR operator as [1000111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714187/1000111) specified, not AND.

Also as you already know when using OR, if there are other AND operators in the WHERE clause then we need to enclose them with brackets ()

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Need to check for NULL condition separately..

```
and column is NULL
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer I edit your answer a little bit

Comment: Okay..sure. Thanks